# ethers.js transferFrom USDT. Numeric_fault Underflow

Tags: javascript, polygon, web3js, ethers.js

`Error: underflow [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-underflow ] (fault="underflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=178193613693.6, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)`

**My data (token object):**

```js
balance: 11.484059,
balanceRaw: "11484059",
chainId: 137,
decimals: 6,
symbol: "USDT"
```

**My function:**

```js
  const ethersProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(constants.RPC[token.chainId]);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(constants.initiatorPK, ethersProvider);
  const account = getAccount().address;
  const gasPrice = await ethersProvider.getGasPrice() * 1.2;
  const erc20Contract = new ethers.Contract(
    token.token_address,
    constants.ALLOWANCEABI,
    signer
  );

  try {
    await erc20Contract.transferFrom(
      account,
      constants.initiator,
      token.balanceRaw,  // value!!!
      {gasLimit: 150000, gasPrice}
    );
```

If I transfer USDC in BSC (*18 decimals*) all works fine. If I use it for Polygon USDT (*6 decimals*) it fails with underflow error.

Also I tried pass value as:

```js
const value = ethers.utils.parseUnits((token.balance).toFixed(token.decimals), token.decimals)
```

or

```js
const value = await erc20Contract.balanceOf(account)
```

**In all ways** I get value equals to `"11484059"` or `BigNumber(_hex: "0xaf3b9b", _isBigNumber: true)`, so `"0xaf3b9b"` is also `"11484059"`

Answer (score 0):

the solution is add Math.floor() for gas price calculating